# Postgresql parameterized query for Crystal Reports SQL Command

Tags: postgresql, parameters, crystal-reports, parameterized

I'm using the following Postgresql select statement in a Crystal report as a SQL Command and it works beautifully. Now I want to change it so that it will use dates passed to it as parameters instead of them being hard-coded like they are below (the parameters are year, monthstart and monthend).

The program I'm using to run the report (Spire) passes parameters like this ?ReportStart or ?ReportEnd when a report is run. I tried replacing the monthstart date '2020-04-01' with ?ReportStart (like this: ?ReportStart::date as monthstart) but I get an error stating "column "reportstart" does not exist".

I also tried 1$, 2$ and 3$ which I read about in the Postgresql PREPARE documentation but it seems I don't quite understand how to write that properly.

````
``` with params as (select '2019-01-01'::date as year, '2020-04-01'::date as monthstart, '2020-04-30'::date as monthend) SELECT h.salesperson_no, h.territory_code, h.cust_no, h.cust_name, i.part_no, i.description,
   SUM(i.committed_qty) FILTER
    (WHERE h.invoice_date >= p.year AND h.invoice_date < p.year + interval '1 year') as LYQty,
   SUM(i.committed_qty * i.unit_price) FILTER
    (WHERE h.invoice_date >= p.year AND h.invoice_date < p.year + interval '1 year') as LYSales,
   SUM(i.committed_qty * i.unit_price) FILTER
    (WHERE h.invoice_date >= p.year AND h.invoice_date < p.monthend - interval '1 year') as LYTDSales,
   SUM(i.committed_qty) FILTER
    (WHERE h.invoice_date >= p.year + interval '1 year' AND h.invoice_date < p.year + interval '2 years') as YTDQty,
   SUM(i.committed_qty * i.unit_price) FILTER
    (WHERE h.invoice_date >= p.year + interval '1 year' AND h.invoice_date < p.year + interval '2 years') as YTDSales,
   SUM(i.committed_qty) FILTER 
     (WHERE h.invoice_date >= p.monthstart AND h.invoice_date <= p.monthend) as MTDQty,
   SUM(i.committed_qty * i.unit_price) FILTER
     (WHERE h.invoice_date >= p.monthstart AND h.invoice_date <= p.monthend) as MTDSales FROM params p
   CROSS JOIN sales_history h
   LEFT JOIN sales_history_items i
          ON i.invoice_no = h.invoice_no WHERE i.part_no is not null AND h.invoice_date >= p.year AND h.invoice_date < p.year + interval '2 years' GROUP BY h.salesperson_no, h.territory_code, h.cust_no, h.cust_name, i.part_no, i.description ```
````

Any guidance for properly adding parameters to a select statement in postgresql would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I apologize that you have to scroll right on this code snippet. For some reason I can't get my code to stay all in one box without removing some of the hard returns.

Comment: I'm not following, is the above being run in Crystal Reports or Spire? What is Spire? Where is the error appearing?

Comment: It's being run in Spire which is a Canadian business management system. Spire uses a postgresql db. That said, if I could just get this figured out in Crystal Reports, I'd be happy. Or even in postgresql. For instance, I don't even know if I should be able to create a parameter in this select statement so that I can run it in pgadmin and have it to ask me for the dates.

Comment: First I would create a simple query to experiment. Second with that simple query tell us exactly where you are inputting the query and show the exact query.  As to `PREPARE`: A simple example `prepare reportplan (date, date, date) AS select * from some_table where year = $1, monthstart = $2, monthend = $3`; execute reportplan('2019-01-01', '2020-04-01', '2020-04-30');`

Comment: Thank you Adrian. Your advice has helped me pare things back temporarily and do a bit more learning. I understand the PREPARE usage now and was able to use that in Crystal. I added a DEALLOCATE reportplan; line at the end so that I could use the statement over and over again without complaint that reportplan already exists.